# Getting max number after entering and displaying

Tags: java, arrays

Have this so far, unsure how to get the max method can anyone help?
I need to enter and display my inputs then get the max value from the inputs

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Skillsdemo3 {

    static Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double temperature[] = new double[7];

        enterTemp(temperature);
        displayTemp(temperature);
        maxTemp(temperature); // Method to be implemented
    }

    // Method start
    public static void enterTemp(double temp[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Max temperature for day" + (i + 1));
            temp[i] = myinput.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    // Method end
    // Method display
    public static void displayTemp(double temp[]) {
        System.out.println(" *** Temperature entered *** ");
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Day " + (i + 1) + " " + temp[i]);
        } // end method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using a `stream`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double temperature[] = new double[] {1D, 20D, 63D, 4D, 8D};
        Arrays.stream(temperature).max().ifPresent(System.out::println); // Finding the maximum and printing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array and get the max element, try this code:

```
public static double maxTemp(double[] tem) {
    Arrays.sort(tem);
    return tem[tem.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: @ngueno  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static variable to store the max temperature in the loop where you insert or where you display.

Comment: All methods need to be separate, school project.

Comment: Yes, the maxTemp method return only the value you are retrieve previously or alternatively reloop on temp array, but is not very optimized method